# How do I find and replace unlabeled attribute in JSON database?

Tags: python, json

This is what my JSON database looks like:

```
{
  "name1": {
    "file": "abc"
    "delimiter": "n"
  },
  "name2": {
    "file": "def"
    "delimiter": "n"
    }
}
```

Pretend I want to change "name1" to "renamed".
How would I do this using Python?

Comment: In what way is that "unlabeled"? The label is `name1`

Comment: There isn't a thing before the name. For example, inside "name1" I have a string "abc" that's a "file". "name1" is just by itself.

Comment: The thing "before" it is just the variable holding the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code:

```
dict = {
  "name1": {
    "file": "abc",
    "delimiter": "n"
  },
  "name2": {
    "file": "def",
    "delimiter": "n"
    }
}

{'name1': {'file': 'abc', 'delimiter': 'n'},
 'name2': {'file': 'def', 'delimiter': 'n'}}
```

Add another key using older key contents then delete it

```
dict["rename1"]=dict["name1"]
del dict["name1"]

{'name2': {'file': 'def', 'delimiter': 'n'},
 'rename1': {'file': 'abc', 'delimiter': 'n'}}
```

Comment: How can I define dict as my JSON database without copying and pasting my entire database in the Python code?

Comment: is your JSON database mongodb ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MongoDB. I'm pretty sure my JSON database is not MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to dict and use pythonic way to change the key name

```
a ={
  "name1": {
    "file": "abc",
    "delimitert" : "n"
  },
  "name2": {
    "file": "def",
    "delimiter": "n"
    }
}

a['renamed'] = a.pop('name1')
```